# Android Java Bitmap.getPixels returns array filled with only -1 as values

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I'm having a problem, where I basically want to analyse a Bitmap to find the lowest pixel that is not white on the bitmap. 
That for I wanted to to loop through every row of pixels of the bitmap. See the code:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName);
for(int i = 0; i < bmp.getHeight(); i++){
    int[] pixels = new int[bmp.getWidth()];
    bmp.getPixels(pixels, 0, bmp.getWidth(), 0, i, bmp.getWidth(), 1);
    //Now when a look at the pixels array at this point all the values are set to -1 everytime
}
```

The fileName is valid and the bitmap is loaded, I have double-checked that. Also the pixels cannot all have the same color, because when I look at the file in an image-Viewer it looks like a normal image.
I'm really bored of this problem and I was searching for a few hours and did not find anything useful.

I think it may have something to do with the third parameter, the stride, I do still not understand fully what that parameter is for. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this true for every line? You are checking only the first.

Comment: I think you need: `bmp.getPixels(pixels, 0, bmp.getWidth(), 0, i*bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getWidth(), 1);`. Moreover how do you check the int inside array. You will receive int in the [Color Class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html)

Comment: The third parameter must be bitmap's width. Can be negative.

Comment: @Alepac I don't understand why you are setting the y coordinate to i*bmp.getWidth(), but i'll test if that'll do the trick...
To check the int I convert the array to a hashset to get rid of duplicates. When the size of the set is bigger than 1 there is at least 1 colored pixel in the line

Comment: @Alepac changing the y-coordinate causes a runtime error: y + height must be <= bitmap.height()

Comment: Sorry, I haven't an environment to check the code, I can't be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

It's also possible you're getting the color value with an 4 byte color code, instead of 3 byte color code, where most significant byte is used for transparency. There is no transparency in a bitmap so that byte can be ignored. In other words, you're getting 0xFF000000 for black, which is -16777216 if you're using int(which is a signed 32 bits, or four bytes, and so the leading bit is 1 making it negative) and 0xFFFFFFFF for white, which is -1 if you're using int.

I have found this happens in android when a bitmap has been used for an android View. It does not happen in my experience when you get a bitmap from a camera capture or an image file.

The solution I used was to mask out the transparency byte so none of my color codes are recognized as negative:

```
int color = pixels[i] & 0x00FFFFFF;
```

Answer (score 0):

(Can't add comment. So putting it as answer)

The stride parameter is important.
It is number of bytes used for storing one image row.
It can be same as the width - but may not be.

Your bitmap properties are important when you are reading it as bytes. If it is a 24bit RGB bitmap, and if it has a width of 100 pixels, it needs 3 * 100 = 300 bytes. So stride is 300. If width is not a multiple of 4, it will need as many more bytes to make it 4-byte aligned.

So, check image parameters and try giving correct stride value.