# When do I know a new significant color change is reached between pixels?

Tags: java, android, computer-vision

I'm working on an Android app and would like to locate the edges of an image taken by the phone camera. I have figured that my best bet at locating these edges is by looking for the pixel in between two pixels that are two significant colors. For instance a shade of green and shade of black.

How would I come across this pixel? Is there a range of numbers that correlate with the various colors and there shades? I.e. `100-200` is red, `200-300` is blue, etc.?

Comment: You would first need to know the format of the image, i.e. `JPG`, `PNG`, `BMP`, etc. (there's a lot of different image file formats). You would then need to decompress or parse the binary data in that format to retrieve working pixel data. Then you would need to loop over all of the pixels in that file to check if one pixel, inbetween two other pixels, exhibits a change in significant color (which would be a certain threshold you define). This doesn't touch on different color formats, for instance `RGB`, `ARGB`, `RGBA`, `ICMY`, etc.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Android camera or it's API, but it may turn out that the image isn't directly saved to a file and instead can be read from a stream. In which case you may not have to parse an image file and instead you'll have access to the raw pixel data.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you really are trying to accomplish, but FYI: most edge detection algorithms examine _neighborhoods_ of pixels rather than just single pixels.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection

Answer (score 1):

First, you can use  [android.graphics.Bitmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html).
If your image is from the device camera or device media, you can do this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(activity.getContentResolver(), uri);
```

You may also want a scaled down version of the image so there are less total pixels in the Bitmap; this will help a lot with performance:

```
bitmap = createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmap.getWidth()/scaleFactor, bitmap.getHeight()/scaleFactor, false);
```

Second, to get the pixels you can do this:

```
int [] pixels = new int[bitmap.getWidth() * bitmap.getHeight()];
bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
```

Third, to evaluate red, blue, green, black, white, etc, use the following convention:

```
black = 0x000000
red   = 0xff0000
green = 0x00ff00
blue  = 0x0000ff
white = 0xffffff
```

It is a matter of your exact needs what range you want to use qualify a particular color. I would suggest the a significant change would be calculated by the following:

```
final static int SIGNIFICANT_CHANGE_AMOUNT = 0xff;

int pixelA = pixels[i];
int pixelB = pixels[i+1];
boolean sigChange = false;
int changeInRed = Math.abs(((pixelA & 0xff0000) >> 16) - ((pixelB & 0xff0000) >> 16));
int changeInGreen = Math.abs(((pixelA & 0x00ff00) >> 8) - ((pixelB & 0x00ff00) >> 8));
int changeInBlue = Math.abs(((pixelA & 0x0000ff) >> 0) - ((pixelB & 0x0000ff) >> 0));
int overallChange = changeInRed + changeInGreen + changeInBlue;
if (overallChange > SIGNIFCANT_CHANGE_AMOUNT) {
    sigChange = true;
}
```

You'll still have to write an algorithm to detect an area but I think if you follow the [Flood Fill Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) wiki it will help a lot. I have used the queue-based implementation since the recursive one is not really feasible.

Also note that when you getPixels from a bitmap that has been used as an android view you will want to mask out the transparency byte... you can see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38841555/1212331)